# Условное форматирование в Pandas (Styling)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

У меня есть табличка.

1. Нужно покрасить ячейку из второго столбца (План) в зеленый, если ее значение меньше левого (Факт).
2. Если План больше Факта, то в красный
3. Если они равны - в желтый. 
   Никак не могу разобраться в документации.
   Буду рад любой помощи.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу ваш код и часть даных.

Comment: @KrDanRod, [что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
def highlight(df, col2highlite="plan"):
    ret = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    ret.loc[df["plan"] < df["fact"], col2highlite] = "background-color: green"
    ret.loc[df["plan"] > df["fact"], col2highlite] = "background-color: red"
    ret.loc[df["plan"] == df["fact"], col2highlite] = "background-color: yellow"
    return ret

df.style.apply(highlight, col2highlite="plan", axis=None)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]